Nav2 Planner and Controller Server high CPU consumption
I encountered some unusual behavior with the nav2_planner and nav2_controller processes on my device.
Under normal conditions, my system typically shows around 11% CPU usage for the planner and 70% for the controller. However, today, I noticed something strange: the planner was consuming around 110% of the CPU, and the controller was at an extreme 167%. This spike in CPU usage caused the controller to crash approximately every 10 minutes.
Using Valgrind, I traced the issue and found that an excessive amount of CPU time was being consumed by the PublishCostmap function from the nav2_costmap_2d package. Interestingly, no costmap subscribers were present, which I verified using the ros2 topic info -v command.
After conducting several tests, I discovered that the problem was related to compiling the nav2_costmap_2d package with the -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug option. When I switched to Release mode, the CPU usage returned to normal, and Valgrind's profiling output showed no significant time spent in PublishCostmap.
I’m curious—how can a compile option like this interfere with code execution in such a drastic way?
While I understand that compiling with debug flags can increase resource consumption, an additional full CPU core seems excessive for the costmap_2d package.
Has anyone experienced similar behavior, or can anyone explain why the debug build would cause such an extreme increase in CPU usage?


I discovered that the problem was related to compiling the nav2_costmap_2d package with the -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug option

That sounds like it is to be expected. Release mode has alot of optimizations that occur. There are debugging reasons to want to have the option to use the ... debug build type ;-)
This is a general C++ software compilation concept that is not unique to Nav2 or ROS. You'd see the same thing if you compiled PCL without release flags or even some consumer application like Word (assuming Word is written in C++, which I don't know if it is / isn't).
